# Need some help to understand the difference of these sentences

Tags: grammar

Can any one tell me what is the correct sentence among theses two or I can use both?

1. This is not Peter's house.
2. This house is not Peter's.

Answer (score 2):

So far the answers have scored 0 and -1. Into the fray I rush.

The sentences that you compare are both grammatical. But they emphasize different ideas.

If someone is trying to buy the house on the corner and suggests that he will pay Peter, I might tell him to pay John instead: "This house is not Peter's. It is John's."

If someone is trying to pick Peter up at home and arrives mistakenly at my house, I might tell him to try next door: "This is not Peter's house. That blue one is Peter's house."

The slight difference between the alternatives is the lightly suggested alternative. The first suggests that someone else owns this house. The second suggests that Peter owns some other house.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with [Richard Baker](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/201409/richard-baker) that "You can use both but the first is more usual.".

"This" in first sentence is a Demonstrative Pronoun, but a Demonstrative Adjective in the second.

"Peter's" is a Demonstrative Adjective in first sentence, but a Demonstrative Pronoun in the second.

1. This [Demonstrative Pronoun] is not Peter's [Demonstrative Adjective] house.
2. This [Demonstrative Adjective] house is not Peter's [Demonstrative Pronoun].